# How to add a legend to a circle in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a `gnuplot` script and it draws the figure like this:

[image]

And here is my script:

```
set term pdf size 11,4.7 font "Arial,24"
set output "plot/application.pdf"


set object circle at 9,20 size 0.35 lw 4 fc rgb "red"

plot 'plot/application.csv' using 1:xtic((int($0)%4)==0?sprintf("%d", $0*10):"") title columnheader(1) pt 1 lw 1, \
'' using 2 title columnheader(2) pt 2 lw 1 ps .1 lc rgb "#4169E1", \
'' using 3 title columnheader(3) pt 3 lw 1 ps .1 lc rgb "#DAA520", \
'' using 4 title columnheader(4) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 5, \
'' using 5 title columnheader(5) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9, \
'' using 6 title columnheader(6) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 7, \
'' using 7 title columnheader(7) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 8, \
```

'' using 7 title columnheader(8) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9

So basically I want to add a **legend** corresponding to the added circle, to make it looks like something like this:

[image]

I tried to adjust from `set object` to something like `plot xxx with circles`, but the syntax is always incorrect.

Could anyone give me some help on generating a correct **legend**? Thank you a lot!

I upload my data files here.

```
process1, process2, process3, process4, process5, process6, process7, process8
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
79.69 , 81.42 ,  78.13 ,  87.694 , 78.231  , 80.231  , 78.231 , 73.231
  62.53 , 73.97 ,  61.58 ,  73.539 , 71.401  , 71.401  , 78.401 ,   65.401
49.98 , 62.85 ,  50.50 ,  54.987 , 59.922  , 53.922  , 64.922 , 56.922
35.89 , 43.60 ,  40.41 ,  45.897 , 40.010  , 44.010  , 51.010 , 43.010
29.44 , 33.73 ,  30.85 ,  37.448 , 30.488  , 35.488  , 43.488 , 31.488
20.05 , 25.53 ,  33.86 ,  30.059 , 27.098  , 23.098  , 34.098 , 27.098
19.88 , 20.67 ,  26.25 ,  25.68 ,  20.45  ,  20.45  ,  27.45  , 18.45
19.01 , 20.04 ,  24.25 ,  20.01 ,  19.358 ,  19.358 ,  25.358 , 15.358
21.88 , 18.61 ,  22.06 ,  23.88 ,  20.054 ,  20.054 ,  20.054 , 15.054
21.18 , 18.33 ,  23.67 ,  22.91 ,  19.022 ,  19.022 ,  19.022 , 12.022
17.01 , 20.04 ,  24.25 ,  18.01 ,  23.358 ,  14.358 ,  13.358 , 10.358
19.88 , 14.61 ,  20.06 ,  16.88 ,  21.054 ,  15.054 ,  10.054 , 5.054
16.18 , 12.33 ,  23.67 ,  15.91 ,  16.022 ,  12.022 ,  9.022 , 9.022
```

and my complete script here:

```
set term pdf size 11,4.7 font "Arial,24"
set output "plot/application.pdf"
set datafile separator ","
set offset 0, 0, 0, 0
set multiplot layout 1,1
set size ratio 0.5
set xtics norangelimit
set ytics nomirror
set termoption dashed
set yrange [0:110]
set style data linespoints
set key vertical maxrows 5
 set key top right
set key vertical maxrows 5

set object circle at 9,20 size 0.35 lw 4 fc rgb "red"

plot 'plot/application.csv' using 1:xtic((int($0)%4)==0?sprintf("%d", $0*10):"") title columnheader(1) pt 1 lw 1, \
'' using 2 title columnheader(2) pt 2 lw 1 ps .1 lc rgb "#4169E1", \
'' using 3 title columnheader(3) pt 3 lw 1 ps .1 lc rgb "#DAA520", \
'' using 4 title columnheader(4) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 5, \
'' using 5 title columnheader(5) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9, \
'' using 6 title columnheader(6) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 7, \
'' using 7 title columnheader(7) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 8, \
'' using 8 title columnheader(8) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9, \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot a single point `with circles` and with legend you must have a data source which contains this single point. The most general way to do this, is to use inline data, i.e. plot from `'-'`:

```
set datafile separator ","
plot 'plot/application.csv' using 1:xtic((int($0)%4)==0?sprintf("%d", $0*10):"") title columnheader(1) pt 1 lw 1, \
'' using 2 title columnheader(2) pt 2 lw 1 ps .1 lc rgb "#4169E1", \
'' using 3 title columnheader(3) pt 3 lw 1 ps .1 lc rgb "#DAA520", \
'' using 4 title columnheader(4) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 5, \
'' using 5 title columnheader(5) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9, \
'' using 6 title columnheader(6) pt 4 lw 1 ps .1 lc 7, \
'' using 7 title columnheader(7) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 8, \
'' using 7 title columnheader(8) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9, \
'' using 8 title columnheader(8) pt 5 lw 1 ps .1 lc 9
'-' using 1:2 with circles lw 4 lc rgb 'red' title 'best choice'
9, 20
e
```

With gnuplot 5 you could also define a data block and plot from this:

```
$data <<EOD
9,20
EOD
set datafile separator ","
plot $data using 1:2 lw 4 lc rgb 'red' title 'best choice'
```

The latter solution can also be used with an interactive terminal, where you want to zoom, scroll an replot.

Comment: Hello Christoph, thank you for your help. I tried the first one, but it just does not show any thing...

Comment: Did you run it from a script, or copy&paste? The latter doesn't work properly with inline data. Here, the circle is plotted correctly, but without having your data file I cannot test the whole command.

Comment: I run it from the script. I upload my complete script and data files in the question, could you please take a look if you have time..? Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Ok, it didn't work because you changed the datafile separator... and I missed the "circles" part ;) See my update for a working snippet